# UITableView, floating headers and footers

Tags: ios, uitableview

My question is, is there the way to do in `UITableView` floating Footer, but non-floating Header?
I read about private API and `(BOOL) allowsHeaderViewsToFloat` and `(BOOL) allowsFooterViewsToFloat` methods, but app will be placed in `Appstore`, and with this tricks app may not be approved to AppStore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own methods for this. Using private APIs would get your app rejected immediately, as you know.

I'd try tracking the `contentOffset` in `scrollViewDidScroll:` (`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so its delegate implements the method) and reposition your custom footer view according to the changes.